# Synchronizing and Resampling two timeseries with non-uniform millisecond intraday data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I see in the python [documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#resampling) the ability to resample and synchronize two timeseries. My problem is harder because there is no time regularity in the timeseries. I read three timeseries that have non-deterministic intraday timestamps. However, in order to do most analysis (covariances, correlations, etc) on those two timeseries, I need them to be of the same length.

In Matlab, given three time series `ts1, ts2, ts3` with non-deterministic intraday timestamps, I can [synchronize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.synchronize.html?refresh=true) them by saying

```
[ts1, ts2] = synchronize(ts1, ts2, 'union');
[ts1, ts3] = synchronize(ts1, ts3, 'union');
[ts2, ts3] = synchronize(ts2, ts3, 'union');
```

Note that the time series are already read into a pandas DataFrame, so I need to be able to synchronize (and resample?) with already created DataFrames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Matlab documentation that you've linked to, it sounds like you want to

> Resample timeseries objects using a time vector that is a union of the
>   time vectors of `ts1` and `ts2` on the time range where the two time
>   vectors overlap.

So first you need to find the union of your dataframes' indices:

```
newindex = df1.index.union(df2.index)
```

Then you can recreate your dataframes using this index:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(newindex)
df2 = df2.reindex(newindex)
```

Note that they will have `NaN`s in all of their new entries (presumably this is the same behaviour as in Matlab), it's up to you if you want to fill these, for example `fillna(method='pad')` will fill in null values using the last known value, or you could use `interpolate(method='time')` to use linear interpolation based on the timestamps.

Comment: Thanks that appears to be very close. I get 
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1892, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: It seems like this solution only unions. The Matlab version of union appears to also resample?  "Union — Resample timeseries objects using a time vector that is a union of the time vectors of ts1 and ts2 on the time range where the two time vectors overlap." - Matlab

Comment: For example in Matlab, ts1 is 151527 long. ts2 is 113903 long and ts3 is 122447 long. The code above to union the three timeseries returns each at length 385926. 151527 +  113903 + 122447 = 387877. So Matlab is probably removing duplicates and interpolating? But I can't tell from the documentation.

Comment: This is so incredibly simple! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to `merge` in order to `synchronize` dataframes. Especially we might want to syncronize 2 dataframes with 2 different data fields to keep instead of 1. For example, suppose we have these 3 dataframes with temperature & humidity values to sync:

`df1`

```
    company_id            log_date  temperature
0            4 2020-02-29 00:00:00         24.0
1            4 2020-02-29 00:03:00         24.0
2            4 2020-02-29 00:06:00         23.9
3            4 2020-02-29 00:09:00         23.8
4            4 2020-02-29 00:12:00         23.8
5            4 2020-02-29 00:15:00         23.7
6            4 2020-02-29 00:18:00         23.6
7            4 2020-02-29 00:21:00         23.5
8            4 2020-02-29 00:24:00         23.4
9            4 2020-02-29 00:27:00         23.3
10           4 2020-02-29 00:30:00         24.0
11           4 2020-02-29 00:33:00         21.0
12           4 2020-02-29 00:36:00         22.9
13           4 2020-02-29 00:39:00         23.8
14           4 2020-02-29 00:42:00         22.8
15           4 2020-02-29 00:45:00         21.7
16           4 2020-02-29 00:48:00         22.6
17           4 2020-02-29 00:51:00         21.5
```

`df2`

```
   company_id            log_date  humidity
0           4 2020-02-29 00:00:00     74.92
1           4 2020-02-29 00:05:00     75.00
2           4 2020-02-29 00:10:00     73.10
3           4 2020-02-29 00:15:00     72.10
4           4 2020-02-29 00:20:00     72.00
5           4 2020-02-29 00:25:00     73.00
6           4 2020-02-29 00:30:00     74.00
7           4 2020-02-29 00:35:00     72.10
8           4 2020-02-29 00:45:00     69.00
9           4 2020-02-29 00:50:00     71.92
```

`df3`

```
   company_id            log_date  temperature
0           4 2020-02-29 00:00:00        20.00
1           4 2020-02-29 00:05:00        21.00
2           4 2020-02-29 00:10:00        22.00
3           4 2020-02-29 00:15:00        23.00
4           4 2020-02-29 00:20:00        23.10
5           4 2020-02-29 00:25:00        22.00
6           4 2020-02-29 00:30:00        22.00
7           4 2020-02-29 00:35:00        22.10
8           4 2020-02-29 00:45:00        23.00
9           4 2020-02-29 00:50:00        21.92
```

We can do something like that

```
df1['log_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['log_date'])
df2['log_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['log_date'])
df3['log_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['log_date'])

df_a = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="log_date", by="company_id", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5m"))
df_b = pd.merge_asof(df1, df3, on="log_date", by="company_id", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5m"))
```

And the resultant dataframes;

`df_a`

```
    company_id            log_date  temperature  humidity
0            4 2020-02-29 00:00:00         24.0     74.92
1            4 2020-02-29 00:03:00         24.0     74.92
2            4 2020-02-29 00:06:00         23.9     75.00
3            4 2020-02-29 00:09:00         23.8     75.00
4            4 2020-02-29 00:12:00         23.8     73.10
5            4 2020-02-29 00:15:00         23.7     72.10
6            4 2020-02-29 00:18:00         23.6     72.10
7            4 2020-02-29 00:21:00         23.5     72.00
8            4 2020-02-29 00:24:00         23.4     72.00
9            4 2020-02-29 00:27:00         23.3     73.00
10           4 2020-02-29 00:30:00         24.0     74.00
11           4 2020-02-29 00:33:00         21.0     74.00
12           4 2020-02-29 00:36:00         22.9     72.10
13           4 2020-02-29 00:39:00         23.8     72.10
14           4 2020-02-29 00:42:00         22.8       NaN
15           4 2020-02-29 00:45:00         21.7     69.00
16           4 2020-02-29 00:48:00         22.6     69.00
17           4 2020-02-29 00:51:00         21.5     71.92
```

`df_b`

```
    company_id            log_date  temperature_x  temperature_y
0            4 2020-02-29 00:00:00           24.0          20.00
1            4 2020-02-29 00:03:00           24.0          20.00
2            4 2020-02-29 00:06:00           23.9          21.00
3            4 2020-02-29 00:09:00           23.8          21.00
4            4 2020-02-29 00:12:00           23.8          22.00
5            4 2020-02-29 00:15:00           23.7          23.00
6            4 2020-02-29 00:18:00           23.6          23.00
7            4 2020-02-29 00:21:00           23.5          23.10
8            4 2020-02-29 00:24:00           23.4          23.10
9            4 2020-02-29 00:27:00           23.3          22.00
10           4 2020-02-29 00:30:00           24.0          22.00
11           4 2020-02-29 00:33:00           21.0          22.00
12           4 2020-02-29 00:36:00           22.9          22.10
13           4 2020-02-29 00:39:00           23.8          22.10
14           4 2020-02-29 00:42:00           22.8            NaN
15           4 2020-02-29 00:45:00           21.7          23.00
16           4 2020-02-29 00:48:00           22.6          23.00
17           4 2020-02-29 00:51:00           21.5          21.92
```

In the first we have 2 different data fields `temperature` & `humidity`, and in the second we have 2 different versions of `temperature`. This could be something you are trying to achieve.